# Git fatal message Mac Terminal

Tags: git, macos, terminal

I was customizing the mac terminal with [this profile](https://github.com/cmilr/Git-Beautify-For-MacOS-Terminal) found on Github and everything went fine following the guide, but since then the every time I open the mac terminal, it shows this:

```
git fetch && git status
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or 
a remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.
```

Changing the profile to another one solves the problem, so I think is related to the profile itself. I know nothing about git, sorry if it's too noob...

Any ideas?

SOLVED: It seems that in the shell preferences there was an command marked for executing at startup.

Comment: If the issue is solved, would you mind answering the question or deleting it? (Preferably the former)

Answer (score 0):

Now it's been solved. It wasn't related to git, instead it was the terminal itself which was executing the command at startup. I've unmarked the checkbox in the shell preferences and that's all. So there it is, noob to git and terminal also, hehe... Anyways, if anybody likes to twitch the terminal look, the profile is very nice, thanks to the contributor.